# Usar "document.open" e "document.close" faz alguma diferença?

Tags: javascript, html

Vi em uma determinada resposta do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9616706/3096922) uma pergunta falando sobre como imprimir o conteúdo de iframe.

Acabei me deparando com um trecho de código onde tinha o seguinte:

```
var newWin = window.frames["printf"];
newWin.document.write('<body onload="window.print()">dddd</body>');
newWin.document.close();
```

Fiquei curioso para saber de qual era esse `document.close`. Aí acabei olhando no [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_close.asp).

Lá tem um exemplo de uso de `document.open` e `document.close`, assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open an output stream, add some text, and close the output stream.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.open();
    document.write("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
    document.close();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Porém notei que tanto com `document.close` ou sem, não acontece nada de diferente nos exemplos (o mesmo vale para `document.open`).

Veja sem o `document.open`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open an output stream, add some text, and close the output stream.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.write("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
    document.close();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Veja sem o `document.close`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open an output stream, add some text, and close the output stream.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.open();
    document.write("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Então, afinal de contas, pra que serve `document.open` ou `document.close`?

Eu acho que além de não ter ficado claro pra mim o uso, parece não servir para nada.

Tem algum caso onde eu realmente tenha que usar um ou outro?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## document.open

A operação `document.open` abre um documento para a escrita (*output stream*) e se já houver uma instância de documento em `document`, seu conteúdo é sobrescrito. Veja abaixo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <p>Click the button to open an output stream, add some text, and close the output stream.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        document.open();
        document.close();
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Perceba que apenas de abrir e fechar o fluxo de dados do documento, todo o conteúdo de `document`, que por padrão é a própria página, é sobrescrito.

## document.close

Já a operação `document.close` fecha o documento para escrita, processo inverso de `document.open`. Perceba que se esta operação não for executada após o `document.open`, a *stream* do documento ficará aberta e o próprio navegador entende isso como se a página não estivesse pronta.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <p>Click the button to open an output stream, add some text, and close the output stream.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        document.open();
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Veja que o ícone no navegador indica que a página está carregando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O navegador permanece assim até que a operação `document.close` seja efetuada ou a página recarregada.

## document.write

A operação `document.write` escreve um conteúdo no documento aberto em questão, como era de se esperar. Mas por quê funciona mesmo sem executar o `document.open` antes? Porquê fazer a chamada ao `document.write` em um documento fechado produz uma chamada implícita à `document.open` antes de executar a operação em si, o que explica o porquê do conteúdo ser sobrescrito.

> **Nota**: O fato de `document.write` fazer uma chamada implícita à `document.open` não é previsto nas especificações W3C e, portanto, não deve ser considerado como comportamento padrão no navegador.

Perceba também que `document.write` apenas faz a chamada implícita à `document.open` e não à `document.close`, sendo o último necessário após executar `document.write`.

---

## Tempo de vida do documento

É interessante notar, também, que o fluxo de dados de saída (*output stream*) do documento atual permanece aberto enquanto a página é carregada e é fechado quando a mesma é completamente carregada. Uma maneira de testar isso é executar a operação `document.write` antes que a página seja carregada por completo, como no exemplo abaixo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script>document.write("<h1>StackOverflow em Português</h1>");</script>
  <body>

    <p>Click the button to open an output stream, add some text, and close the output stream.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        document.open();
        document.close();
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Como o documento está aberto durante o carregamento da página, a operação `document.write` não sobrescreve seu conteúdo.

Answer (score 2):

Como o Anderson falou, o `document.open` abre um ***output stream*** e deixa o browser com aquele sinal de carregando, aguardando chamadas de `document.write` e um `document.close` para finalizar.

> Para ilustrar um exemplo de uso do `document.open` podemos ver o
>   uso do `window.open()` e depois juntar com o
>   `document.open`, `document.write` e `document.close` abrindo uma popup e 
>   escrevendo dentro dela.

`window.open()` faz abrir um popup, enquanto `window.close()` fecha o popup. (Não confundir `window` com `document`, um trata da janela e o outro do conteúdo, são coisas diferentes)

**pagina.html**

```
Essa é sua página com botão para abrir janelinha popup. <br>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="window.open('popup.html','_blank','height=200,width=200,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,toolbar=0')" value="Abrir popup">
```

**popup.html**

```
<h1>Abriu sua popup!</h1>
<input type="button" onclick="window.close()" value="Fechar popup">
```

O exemplo acima é um popup chamado do jeito padrão, mas se quisermos fazer um popup sem usar outra página, poderíamos chamar o `document.open`, seguido de  chamadas de `document.write` e um `document.close`.

Segue abaixo agora um exemplo de uso do `document.open` dentro de uma popup que não chama nenhum arquivo e cria o conteúdo dinamicamente.

**gerapopup.html**

```
<script>
function gerapopup()
{
    //Abre popup vazio
    var w = window.open('','_blank','height=150,width=450,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,toolbar=0');

    //Escreve na popup
    w.document.open();
    w.document.write("<h1>Popup gerada dinamicamente</h1>");
    w.document.write('<input type="button" onclick="window.close()" value="Fechar popup">');
    w.document.close();
}
</script>

Essa é sua página com botão para abrir janelinha popup. <br>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="gerapopup()" value="Gerar popup">
```

Nota: Por motivos de segurança popups caíram em desuso mas o teste localmente do código acima ainda funciona satisfatoriamente.